# Is it wrong to use -ed adjectives when using Personification or Transferred Epithet?

Tags: adjectives

I know that

….saying “boring house” ✔️ is correct, and

…saying “bored house” ❌ is incorrect cause a house cannot have the feeling of boredom.

However my point is about personification, when you add a human quality to an object on purpose.

In a discussion with a friend about personifying things, they claim that while you can say for example, a “cruel watch” you cannot say a “bored pencil”.

It seems to me that both examples we follow the form adjective+noum

Consider the following sentence:

> “a bored pencil tapped the school desk while the cruel minute hand
> refused to move”

Their claim is that an adjective that ends in “–ed” can’t be use to personify something, but other adjectives are okay. This feels like splitting hairs.

Comment: I think that the metaphor is stretched but not so much as to break. Differences in the context and wording around it would help.

Comment: A 'bored pencil' in this case is a metaphor and personification can be taken a long way in creative writing. However 'a bored pencil' could, literally, be a pencil with a hole drilled through it, perhaps to pass a piece of string through. Ballot pencils used to be like this.

Comment: Participles as adjective have a particular function. **1**. The present participle "verbing" is in the indicative = which/who/that verbs, e.g. "The dripping tap" the tap that dripped / is dripping, etc. **2**. The past participle "verbed" is in the passive = which/who/that <some tense of to be> verbed. "The dropped plate broke" = the plate that was dropped, etc., broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, I think the sentence:

> A bored pencil tapped the desk while the cruel minute  hand refused to move.

is a perfectly valid sentence. In fact, I think it is extremely evocative of the situation you are conveying. The implication is not that the pencil is bored, but the one tapping it is bored. So I don't agree with your friend's analysis at all.

I am sure that literature is replete with such usages, but, I had a quick look and found this from [Winston Churchill's "The World In Crisis"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_World_Crisis/n99mAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22exhausted%20inheritance%22&pg=PA21&printsec=frontcover):

> The new Prime Minister never had a fair chance. He succeeded only to an **exhausted inheritance**.

In fact the specific case you mention, "bored house" occurs in [H.G. Wells](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Boon_The_Mind_of_the_Race_The_Wild_Asses/utPCDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bored%20house%22&pg=PT130&printsec=frontcover) (though admittedly, he is referring specifically to the British House of commons, and, by metonymy, to the members thereof.)

> I remember how vividly Boon drew the picture for us: the rather **bored House**, a coming and going of a few inattentive Members...

*(From "Boon, The Mind of the Race, the Wild Asses of the DEvil, and The Last Trump")*